# Why socket.io returns "Bad handshake method"?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, socket.io, ngx-socket-io

Good evening,
i'm struggling with a socket connection.
I use socket.io in the nodejs-express backend and ngx-socket-io in the angular frontend, but at the connection i continuosly receive 400 stat ({"code":2,"message":"Bad handshake method"}) alternate with 200 stat width sid: 0{"sid":"REeYoGC5t_JnTp4dAABp","upgrades":"websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}).

[Here there is a screenshot of chrome's net tab][1]

Here it is the server

```
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on " + PORT, colors.yellow);
    init();
});

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
   cors: {
        origin: ["http://localhost:4200", "https://myurl.com",],
        credentials: true
    }
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {

    console.log("Connected");

    socket.emit("ok","ok");
    socket.on("disconnect", (data) => {

    });
});
```

And here there is the client

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = { 
    url: environment.SERVER_ENDPOINT, 
    options: { autoConnect: false, withCredentials: true}  
};

...
imports: [
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
]
...
```

Can someone help me with this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/72YSB.png

EDIT
I've resolved this using socket.io-client instead of ngx-socket-io

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have the exact same version of socket.io on client and server?  Bad Handshake can often be because of mismatched versions.  Are you loading the client-side socket.io from your server directly (which makes sure you would have the same version) or are you loading it from a CDN?

Comment: I’m loading it from CDN

Comment: Then, you probably don't have matching versions.  What exact socket.io version are you running on the server?  What is the exact CDN URL you are loading?

Comment: "socket.io": "^3.0.4" on server

Comment: "ngx-socket-io": "^3.2.0", on client

Comment: Well, as I said, you need the SAME version in client and server.  If you get the browser script directly from the server with `/socket.io/socket.io.js`, then you are guaranteed to get the same version as the server.   I would strongly recommend giving that a try.  If the client is not from a browser, then you need to get the matching client version and install and use that version in your client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to downgrade version , it was fine with socket.io 2.3.1